# Is this regex to find the 'out' in my outbound links correct?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to generate an Analytics event when any of my tracked links are clicked

My links are [www.domain.com/out/link1](http://www.domain.com/out/link1)

I've found some JS online that was originally for tracking any domain that is NOT the current domain, and changed it to track any link that contains the text "/out" ... but I'm not sure it is correct.

```
<!-- Track Outbound Links -->
<script type=”text/javascript“>
  var a = document.getElementsByTagName(‘a’);
  for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    if (a[i].href.indexOf('out') != -1 && a[i].href.match(/^https:///i)){
      a[i].onclick = function(){
        _gaq.push([‘_trackEvent’, ‘outgoing_links’, this.href.replace(/^https:///i, ”)]);
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Would anybody who is more skilled in JS than me let me know what needs to be tweaked to make it work?

This was the original script:

```
<script type=”text/javascript“>

var a = document.getElementsByTagName(‘a’);
for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
if (a[i].href.indexOf(location.host) == -1 && a[i].href.match(/^http:///i)){
a[i].onclick = function(){
_gaq.push([‘_trackEvent’, ‘outgoing_links’, this.href.replace(/^http:///i, ”)]);
}
}
}

</script>
```

Cheers

Comment: An easy way to test this is comment out the _gaq line and replace it with `console.log`. That way you can test to see if it is being triggered correctly. Have you tested it out?

Comment: I did, and it's not printing anything so clearly it's not running. What would do match part be doing? It's just making sure that the current href is the one being clicked right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to check for `==-1` but if the result is `> -1`

I've added the sample code below. You can insert your tracking code to the `//add your function` part

```js
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
var regex = /^http:/ //i
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  if (a[i].href.indexOf('\out')  > -1 && a[i].href.match(regex)) {
        a[i].onclick = function clicked(url){
        console.log('clicked url');
      // Add your function here
    };
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="http://google.com">Google link</a>
<a href="http://twitter.com/out">Twitter link</a>
```